# I need to set three click listeners on one button

Tags: android, android-studio, event-listener

I have made this button which I have named save. So basically what I need is that password, avatar and the name get changed and saved at the click of the save button. Right now I could get the button to perform only one function at the click of the button.

Comment: have one click listener and boolean flags and do what is required based on true or false

Answer (score 1):

For One button you just need one click listener..
You have to think in another way.. You have to handle that click with your functionality..
Easiest way will be using boolean flags.

You have to keep a count of clicks, with each click you have to change each boolean flags.
consider flags like

```
boolean saveflag,passwordflag,avatarflag =false;
```